# Can one claim charitable contribution deduction for data donation?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, donation

If one paid some amount of money to acquire some data, then donate the data to a  qualified tax-exempt organization, can one claim charitable contribution deduction for it in the United States?

Example: paying to sequence one's whole genome sequence, then giving the data to a qualified tax-exempt organization that does research on genomics.

Comment: Were you purchasing information on behalf of the organisation? Presumably the data has some relevance to the organisation’s operations - but in that case, wouldn’t they have already purchased it themselves?

Comment: @Lawrence 
Example: paying to sequence one's whole genome sequence, then donating the data to a qualified tax-exempt organization that does research on genomics.

Comment: Is there a market for that? If the organization wanted data from more individuals, could they go to a seller and ask "give me 10 genetic sequences, here take these $"? Or do they offer to pay any amount to individuals wishing to sell that data?

Comment: Up to the eleven: if the relatives/heir of a deceased person allow for his remains to be used for organ donation/research, do they get (as owners of the body) to deduct that as donations?

Comment: @SJuan76 There might be a market for that. As far as I know, they don't offer to pay any amount to individuals wishing to sell that data. Regarding the body donation for deceased person, maybe it's a bit different as I don't know if the  body of the deceased person belongs to the heirs, and as a result if the relatives/heir of a deceased person allow for his remains to be used for organ donation/research  don't know  if this counts as a donation.

Comment: Do you still have access to the data?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep yes

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: We already recently explored blood and organ donations, and found that there's no advantage (you can only claim a deduction up to the value of *imputed* income you should have received from the sale, which exactly cancels the deduction).  In this case at least you have an expense in excess of the imputed income, so it might be possible... but since you are donating merely a copy of the data, it is unlikely that each copy would be held to have a valuation equal to acquiring the first copy.

Comment: @BenVoigt maybe one can deduct just for the first copy?

Comment: How much did it cost you? The IRS requirements for level of documentation depend on the value of the item.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep 's comment here can prob be expanded to an answer. All donations require a receipt. Non-cash donations require the receipt and above a certain amount, an appraisal.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Between 200 USD and 2000 USD.

Answer (score 1):

It really depennds how much the taxman will believe that you gifting the data cost you.

You would be better positioned if you had contracted the organisation to have your genome sequenced